# Have I ruined my Japanese maple by over-pruning?

Tags: pruning, maple

I pruned the dead bits off my Bihou Acer two weeks ago. Now there are no leaves and the stems are going black. Have I wrecked it?

Comment: Can you add a photo  please? Otherwise, how long have you had the plant, and is it in a pot or in the ground? And you only pruned off dead bits, not live wood?

Comment: Before and after photos if you have them so that we can compare them and see what you did. Thanks!